# How to redirect away from login page TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a login page with FeLogin form inside of it: `example.com/login`

I wanted my application to redirect me to login page when the user is not logged in, i also wanted to redirect to another page after successful login.

Both worked just fine with me using FeLogin form with redirects. But, now when the user hits the url again `example.com/login` the form will be gone and it will be `logout` which is also fine. but since the login page only contain the form. this won't make sense. so i want that when the user is logged in and they hit the login url `example.com/login` to be redirected to the same page after login `example.com/home`.

I have enabled the login redirect upon user group -so i can make different redirects depending on groups- so i tried to add this:

```
[usergroup = *]
    config.typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages = 2
    config.typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages_addParams = &return_url=http://example.com/home
[end]
```

my login page id is 2.
but this is not working. neither the following:

```
[usergroup = *]
    page.config >
    page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: example.com/home
[else]
    page.config >
    page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: example.com/login
[end]
```

nothing i tried in config will work, &return_url or &redirect_url
they will all work when i have a typo3 link linked to these then it will work otherwise i cannot figure out a way to make this happen.

the scenario
- user login on /login
- redirect to /home page
- user hits /login url again
- (how can i redirect to /home page?) <<<<< this is my problem

it should only be like this when they are logged in.

Comment: Did you try to use `config.additionalHeaders` instead of `page.config.additionalHeaders`?

Comment: yes and it didnt work

Comment: it will work in case i hade a typolink linking to the login page

Comment: but it wont work if you manually open the /login. users might save the url as bookmark

Comment: have you tried adding a ext template just for the login page to make sure there is nothing overwriting your condition?